# Weird behavior of BehaviorSubject, async pipe, and *ngIf combination: ngOnChanges receives the change that theoretically cannot be possible

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ng-if, behaviorsubject

I have two components - Parent component which fetches the data from the server, and child component which is displaying fetched entries as a list - **but only if the list is not null or empty**.

My problem is (short): Even if there is `*ngIf` checking that the list has some values, emission is done and in child component I get first emission with `null` items: [![First emission] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHRB5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHRB5.png).

Second emission is though okay... [![Secod emission] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK8Op.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK8Op.png).

Does somebody have an idea?

---

The parent component also contains search field where you can search entries. Here is the code:

```
<lookup-area [debounceTime]="100"
             (searchValue)="searchChanged($event)"></lookup-area>

<app-virtual-list *ngIf="(channels$ | async)?.length > 0"
                  [items]="channels$ | async"
                  [itemHeightPx]="32"
                  [maxContainerHeightPx]="190 - ((channels$ | async)?.length ? 29 : 0)"
                  [trackByFn]="trackByFn">
    <ng-template let-item>Some template</ng-template>
</app-virtual-list>
```

```
@Component({
             selector: 'app-filter',
             templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
             changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
             encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
           })
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    public search$ = new BehaviorSubject('');

    constructor(private service: YoutubeSearchService) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.channels$ = combineLatest([this.service.getYoutubeChannels(), this.search$]).pipe(
            map(([channels, search]) => search ? channels.filter(channel => (channel.name || channel.id).startsWith(search)) : channels),
            map(channels => channels?.sort((a, b) => (a.name || a.id).localeCompare((b.name || b.id), undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' })))
        );
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.search$.complete();
    }

    public searchChanged(search: string): void {
        this.search$.next(search);
    }

    public trackByFn(index: number, item: YoutubeChannel): any {
        return item.id;
    }

}
```

---

And the child component contains the logic for displaying. Here is the code:

```
@Component({
             selector: 'app-virtual-list',
             templateUrl: './virtual-list.html',
             styleUrls: ['./virtual-list.less'],
             changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
             encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
           })
export class VirtualList<T> implements OnChanges {

  // Mandatory
  @Input() public items: T[];
  @Input() public itemHeightPx: number;

  // Optional
  @Input() public maxContainerHeightPx: number | undefined; // If undefined, scroll container's height is 100%

  
  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      const { items, itemHeightPx, maxContainerHeightPx } = changes;

      if (this.maxContainerHeightPx && (items || itemHeightPx || maxContainerHeightPx)) {
         this.setContainerScrollHeight();
      }
  }

}
```

I tried:

1. wrapping everything in `<ng-container *ngIf="(channels$ | async)?.length > 0">`, but no success
2. wrapping in another `div`, still did not work

I have no clue what else to try because it seems that `*ngIf` does not work which is really weird.

I would expect that the first change comes with the items inside since that is what `*ngIf` is telling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your issue, but I already see a bad thing in your code, so try to resolve it and see if the issue persists.

You don't need to create 3 subscriptions, a single one is enough.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="channels$ | async as channels">
  <app-virtual-list 
    *ngIf="channels?.length"
    [items]="channels"
    [itemHeightPx]="32"
    [maxContainerHeightPx]="190 - (channels?.length ? 29 : 0)"
    [trackByFn]="trackByFn"
  >
    <ng-template let-item>Some template</ng-template>
  </app-virtual-list>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My problem is that even if there is *ngIf=(channels$ | async)?.length > 0 and the channels list is empty, I am getting emission in app-virtual-list...

Comment: Well your ngOnChanges function triggers not only for items, but for all inputs, you are aware of that right ?

Comment: Sure, but it should not even be rendered if there are no channels, and therefore not triggered

Comment: And just FYI, it will not create 3 subscriptions, but only 1. But I agree that it looks better as you did it.

Comment: It's triggered if the inputs change. You don't provide enough code for us to know if that's the case, so I wanted to make sure you knew that. And no, 3 `async` means 3 subscriptions, look at the source code of the pipe if you don't believe me